# Are “ten billionths” ten times smaller or ten times larger than “one billionth”?

Tags: numbers

One billionth of a meter is equal to one meter divided by a billion.

What are ten billionths of a meter?

Source for the phrase “ten billionths of a meter” is a [TED-Ed video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2Y0GMCFWq0). It is said at the very beginning of the video.

Comment: A ten billionth of a meter is 0.1 billionths of a meter. Ten billionths of a metre is 10 times a billionth of a meter.

Comment: It's ambiguous.  Could mean 10 one-billionths of a meter or could mean 1 ten-billionth of a meter.  The use of plural "billionths" suggests that 10 one-billionths is the intended value, but notation is confusing at best.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. You know what one billionth is; ten billionths is obviously ten of them, right?

Comment: This is why proper use of hyphens is important. A birthday party for thirty-six-year-olds is very different from a birthday party for thirty six-year-olds.

Answer (score 1):

In the video, the narrator says "this round structure is only about ten billionths of a meter in diameter". In that expression, that can only be interpreted as 10 nanometers, which is 10^-8 meters. That's what he said, and that is reflected in the closed captions.

But the text written in the video itself says 10^-10 m., which is 100 times smaller.

The video is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

> One billionth of a meter is equal to one meter divided by a billion.

Correctly, this should be

One **one billionth** of a meter is equal to one meter divided by a billion.

We know this as

Two **one billionths** of a meter is equal to twice one meter divided by a billion.

whereas

One **two billionth** of a meter is equal to one meter divided by two billion.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the nanosecond. Is 10 nanoseconds(10*10^-9 second) larger or smaller than 1 nanosecond(1*10^-9 second).

Mathematics prefers the decimal (or hexadecimal in specific areas) system. There are two scales used for "larger than 1000" numbers, short and long. The short scale uses multiples of 1000 and is the most commonly used.  If it was 1*10^-10 ten billionths won't be used for that. The correct term would be 100 trillionths(100*10^-12)

Source: Wikipedia (Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales)